# How to get the id of a dynamically created html button on its click in jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have several(inside loop) `dynamically` created `html` `buttons` like :

```
sb.Append("<input type=\"button\"  name=\"deleteimage" + id 
              + " \" id=\"btndelete" + id 
              + "\" value=\"Delete\" class=\"t-button t-grid-delete\" " 
              + " style=\"margin-left:10px;\" />");
```

and I want to get the `id` of the `button` on which I `click` using `jquery`

Help Me

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

delegate using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)(jQuery 1.7+) or [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)(jQuery 1.6 and lower)

```
$('body').on('click','input[type=button]',function(){
     alert(this.id); // <-- this refers to current clicked input button
});
```

or

```
$('body').delegate('input[type=button]','click',function(){
     alert(this.id);
});
```

Or whatever your sb element is replace body with that since it exists on dom load

Comment: @pwn yw.   Hope it helped you.  Don't forget to click the green check mark if it answered your question

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
$('input:button').click(function(){
    alert('Clicked ' + this.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("input[type=button]").click(function()
{
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
$(document).click(function(event) { 
        var target = event.target;      
        if ($(target).hasClass("t-grid-delete")) { // check if element has class t-grid-delete is your button
            var targetId =  $(target).attr("id");
            // set your image id with attribute like image_id
            // it take easy to get image id $(target).attr("image_id")
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'live' event for dynamically generated html element's event

```
$("input[type=button]").live('click',function()
{
    alert(this.id);
});
```